# Add days to timestamp and get a timestamp back

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL I could not find a function that adds days to a timestamp and receive a timestamp back, and I can use a calculated value to do so.

This works, but **static**

```
SELECT col1 + interval 2 days FROM 

VALUES make_timestamp(2021, 12, 28, 6, 30, 45.887)
```

I need one that I can **calculate**. This doesn't work (I cannot fill it with column value either):

```
SELECT col1 + interval (5-3) days 

FROM VALUES make_timestamp(2021, 12, 28, 6, 30, 45.887)
```

This is **not good** either (as it gives a date back):

```
SELECT date_add(col1,1) FROM 

VALUES make_timestamp(2021, 12, 28, 6, 30, 45.887)
```

Comment: Can you try your last solution but just wrapping it with `to_timestamp(date_add(col1,1))`

Comment: Unfortunately that solution truncates the hour, min, second to zero

Comment: String interpolation, val ndays=5-3; val sql= s"SELECT col1 + interval $ndays days FROM .."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using directly interval constructor, you can build a string representing your interval with [`concat` SQL function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#concat) and then cast it to an interval with [`cast` SQL function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#cast):

```sql
SELECT col1 + cast(concat(5-3, ' days') as interval)

FROM VALUES make_timestamp(2021, 12, 28, 6, 30, 45.887)
```

which returns the following result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(col1 + CAST(concat(CAST((5 - 3) AS STRING),  days) AS INTERVAL) AS TIMESTAMP)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2021-12-30 06:30:45.887                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is to convert timestamp to unix time and add desired number of seconds.

```
scala> spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2021-10-15 10:11:12') + 10 * 24*60*60) plus10days").show(false)
+-------------------+
|plus10days         |
+-------------------+
|2021-10-25 10:11:12|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Good solution @mazaneicha but I was looking for the one above!

Comment: Thanks, understood! They both have their +es and -es :)